# Cacti return 0 from data sources, OID of snmp is different

Tags: cacti

I have installed and configured cacti successfully on Debian 11.
Only one problem: I cannot get network statistics and disk partitions form snmp
Cacti said..

```
Total: 0.020000, Delta: 0.020000, Executing SNMP get for num of indexes @ '.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.1.0' Index Count:
Total: 0.020000, Delta: 0.000000, Executing SNMP walk for list of indexes @ '.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1' Index Count: 0
Total: 0.020000, Delta: 0.000000, No SNMP data returned
```

snmpwalk works fine

```
snmpwalk -v3 -l authPriv -u myuser -a SHA512 -A "password" -x AES -X "password" cacti1.server  IF-MIB::ifDescr.2
IF-MIB::ifDescr.2 = STRING: eth0
```

System is Debian 11, both server and monitored client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround found.

I have recreated user using MD5 (sic!) and DES instead of aes..now works fine.

```
net-snmp-config --create-snmpv3-user -ro -A MD5 -X DES -a passs -x pass myuser
```

I would prefer the most secure sha512+AES but give problems.

Also the line

```
net-snmp-config --create-snmpv3-user -ro -A MD5 -X AES -a passs -x pass myuser
```

works fine